# How does this audio power amplifier circuit work?

Tags: operational-amplifier, power, audio, power-electronics, multisim

[How do I simulate an audio amplifier in Multisim?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/76843/how-do-i-simulate-an-audio-amplifier-in-multisim/495960#495960)

I'm required to search for audio power amplifier circuit and explain how it works in details so I need to know the detailed process of this circuit and understand how does it work?
also I found this circuit from here SE

[image]

Comment: Q1: Is this an assignment?  Q2: What do you know about op-amps?  Q3: Where did you get the circuit from. As shown it is incomplete and would not work properly. [Hint: The DC level of pin 2 MUST be defined]  | Search the web for "zoebel network".

Comment: yes it is an assignment and I dont know much about op-amps and I got this circuit from this here stack exchange

Comment: Please show the stack exchange page address || Q4: What is the actual assignment? ie if you must supply the circuit what are you actually required to do?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/76843/how-do-i-simulate-an-audio-amplifier-in-multisim/495960#495960

Comment: I'm required to search for audio power amplifier circuit and explain how it works

Comment: @Fatima, welcome to EE.SE. All that information you have supplied should be added to your question, not hidden in the comments. Please [edit] your question to add it in.

Comment: @Fatima, if you can search for **any** processor why would you select one you don't understand?

Comment: I need help in this please

Comment: @FatimaAljneibi Unfortunately you have NOT chosen a "normal" circuit. The cct relates to a TDA2002 IC - [datasheet here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/dm00028077.pdf) which has unusual connections. Pin 2 is allowed to have "AC coupling" via  aa capacitor with this IC. This is NOT the case for every amplifier IC. I suggest that you look at the TDA2040 circuit [**here**](http://www.theorycircuit.com/25-watt-audio-power-amplifier-circuit/) which is very very similar BUT which connects the IC in a more standard manner.

Comment: You might be better off looking for a discrete transistor audio power amp, and explaining that. The details are visible there, instead of being hidden in an opaque triangular block.

Comment: I cant seem to find simple one since Q point and Amplifier classification are required most of the circuits are with op-amp

Comment: You need to tell us ALL of your requirement "up front" so we can help you with the actual question. Note that while we do not "just answer" assignment type questions we are happy to help people understand such problems as long as they show effort in attempting to answer. || Q1: What is Qpoint (quiescent point -  DC operating point or perhaps Class A AB B C ... biasing? or ...?)

Comment: I will post the assignment requirement in another question sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you have NOT chosen a "normal" circuit.
The chosen circuit relates to a TDA2002 IC - [datasheet here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/dm00028077.pdf) which has unusual connections.
With this IC Pin 2 is allowed to have "AC coupling" via  a capacitor due to the IC being "unusually constructed" internally.
This is NOT the case for every amplifier IC or for standard opamps - the diagram you are using would not work wity standard opamps or many other amplifier ICs.

I suggest that you look at the TDA2040 circuit [**here**](http://www.theorycircuit.com/25-watt-audio-power-amplifier-circuit/) which is very very similar BUT which connects the IC in a more standard manner.

[TDA2040 datasheet here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00000130.pdf)
The diagram below is taken from fig 13 of the datasheet.

This diagram, from the above page, operates in a standard manner and is a MUCH better example for your purposes.

**DO NOT** just copy the following.  Use it as a starting point for understanding. Ask questions if you need to.

R2 & R3 set the DC level of the amplifier's pin 1 input at about half supply voltage.
R5 ensures that Vout properly tracks the pin 1 DC level.
R5 and R4 set the AC gain.
R6 C6 is a Zobel network - Google knows.
C3 blocks DC from the speaker.

[image]

**______________________________________________**

**SIMPLE ALTERNATIVE:**

OR the LM358 circuit from [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/421518/speaker-problem-with-high-volume/421701#421701) SE EE question is very simple and may suit your need.

Note - this is a "preamplifier" in that it amplifies the microphone signal to a level suited to the main amplifier. It does however demonstrate the principles that you are required to explain, except for the power level.

Comment: Thank you sir I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

This is just a simple Opamp .R2,R3 are sized for a closed loop gain of 101 .The output stage is more robust than normal opamps so it will drive a low impedance speaker .Biasing is internal so the audio is AC coupled with C1.C2.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You are correct re the internal biasing, but that risks being "hand wavium" for the OP. If they are asked to explain it they will be unable to do so.
Note that pin 2 has NO DC coupling. The circuit will not work for a standard opamp. The TDA2002 which this applies to has a transistor input stage where pin 2 is effectively ground and pin 3 is single ended AC coupled input